# codigo de python - juego de poker

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Se supone que el script toma la entrada de un archivo de texto que está en formato abreviado para manos de póquer y lo convierte al formato completo correcto. Actualmente está haciendo la mayor parte de eso correctamente, pero no está leyendo correctamente la información de los archivos csv y poniéndolos en el formato de salida final. Hay dos archivos csv. Uno tiene las cantidades de fichas de los jugadores y el otro tiene las cartas de los jugadores. Hay secciones en la salida para cada mano donde se supone que debe ir esta información, pero hay un error que hace que la información no se coloque allí correctamente. Le enviaré un ejemplo de los archivos de entrada, así como el archivo de salida actual y un archivo de salida corregido que muestra lo que se supone que debe suceder. Si tiene alguna pregunta sobre esto, hágamelo saber.

Se supone que los archivos: input, InChips y DealtTo son los archivos de entrada que utiliza el script. El archivo de salida muestra lo que el script está procesando actualmente. Correct Output.txt muestra cómo se supone que debe terminar. Básicamente, se supone que la información de InChips.csv va donde dice (ERROR) está después del nombre de cada jugador y se supone que la información de DealtTo.CSV va después de la sección *** HOLECARDS como en el archivo Correct Output.txt.

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

class PokerGame():
    def __init__(self, game_input, deal, chips):
        self.game_input = game_input
        self.deal = deal
        self.chips = chips
        self.log = []
    
    def get_hands(self):
        # Split the input string into a list of lines.
        lines = self.game_input.split("\n")
        
        # Get the indices for each empty line.
        empty_lines = []
        i = 0
        flag = True
        while flag:
            try:
                i = lines.index("", i+1)
                empty_lines.append(i)
            except:
                flag = False
        
        # Get the seat assignments from the input.
        if empty_lines[0]!=1:
            self.log.append("Warning: it looks like you don't have the seat assignment in the expected format or there are not 8 players.")
        seat_input = "\n".join(lines[empty_lines[0]+1:empty_lines[1]])
        
        # Get a list of each hand from the input input.
        hand_inputs = []
        if len(empty_lines)>2:
            for i in range(len(empty_lines[1:])-1):
                hand_inputs.append("\n".join(lines[empty_lines[i+1]+1:empty_lines[i+2]]))
            hand_inputs.append("\n".join(lines[empty_lines[i+2]+1:]))
        else:
            hand_inputs.append("\n".join(lines[empty_lines[1]+1:]))
        
        hands = []
        dt = datetime.datetime.today()
        for hand_input in hand_inputs:
            hand, log_ = PokerHand(hand_input, seat_input, self.deal, self.chips).make_hand(dt)
            hands.append(hand)
            self.log.append(log_)
            dt = dt + datetime.timedelta(0, 60)
        hands = "\n\n".join(hands)
        return hands
    
    def output_hands(self, filename):
        hands = self.get_hands()
        with open(filename, 'w') as f:
            f.writelines(hands)
        with open("log.txt", "w") as f:
            f.writelines("\n".join(self.log))

class PokerHand():
    def __init__(self, hand_input, seat_input, deal, chips):
        self.hand_input = hand_input
        self.seat_input = seat_input
        self.deal = deal
        self.chips = chips
        self.log = []
        
    def make_hand(self, datetime):
        # Get the IDs of the players and put it in the list 
        # seat_assignment in order of the seats 1 through 8.
        try:
            seat_lines = self.seat_input.split("\n")
            seat_assignment = []
            for line in seat_lines:
                seat_assignment.append(line.strip().split(" ")[1])
        except:
            self.log.append("Error parsing seat assignment. All hands will potentially be effected.")
            seat_assignment = ["error"]*8
        
        # Get the info needed from the first line of the hand input.
        # This line should always be of the form "hand X- [py[/pz...] not at table]"
        try:
            lines = self.hand_input.split("\n")
            first_line = lines[0].strip().split(" ")
            if first_line[0][0]=="*":
                self.log.append("A hand labelled with * was skipped.")
                return "THIS HAND WAS LABELLED WITH * AND THUS SKIPPED", "\n".join(self.log)
            hand_number = first_line[1][:-1]
        except:
            self.log.append("Error parsing first line of an unknown hand.")
            self.log.append("\t Due to this error, the hand number will read 'XXXX' for this hand.")
            hand_number = "XXXX"
        try:
            if len(first_line)>2:
                if first_line[2].isascii() and len(first_line[2])>0: 
                    not_at_table = first_line[2].split("/")
                else:
                    not_at_table = []
            else:
                not_at_table = []
        except:
            self.log.append(f"Error parsing first line of hand {hand_number}.")
            self.log.append(f"\t This line is expected to be in the form 'hand {hand_number}- pa/pb/pc not at table' where 'pa/pb/pc' are a list of players seperated by '/'.")
            not_at_table = []
        
        # Get the info needed from the second line.
        # This line should always be of the form "blinds X/Ya[/Z...]"
        try:
            blinds = lines[1].strip().split(" ")[1].split("/")
            assert len(blinds)>1
            assert all([blind.isalnum() for blind in blinds])
        except:
            self.log.append(f"Error parsing the second line of hand {hand_number}.")
            blinds = ["err","err"]

        # Get the info from the third line.
        # This line should always be of the form "x/y/z[/a...]"
        try:
            third_line = lines[2].strip().split("/")
            
            assert all([seat.isalnum() for seat in third_line])
        except:
            self.log.append(f"Error parsing the third line of hand {hand_number}.")
        
        try:
            button_seat = third_line[0]
        except:
            self.log.append(f"Error parsing the third line of hand {hand_number}.")
            button_seat = "error"
        try:
            blind_sitters = [seat_assignment[int(i)-1] for i in third_line[1:]]
            # assert len(blind_sitters)=len(blinds)
        except:
            self.log.append(f"Potential error in third line of hand {hand_number} or in the seat assignment.")
            blind_sitters = ["error"]*(len(blinds))
        
        ante_dict = dict()
        try:
            for sitter in seat_assignment:
                ante_dict[sitter] = "$0"     
        except:
            self.log.append(f"Potential error in the seat assignment.")
            for i in range(1,9):
                ante_dict[f"error{i}"] = "$0"  
        try:
            for i, blind in enumerate(blinds):
                if blind[-1]=='a':
                    ante_dict[blind_sitters[1]] = f"${int(blind[:-1]):,}"
                    blinds[i] = blind[:-1]
        except:
            self.log.append(f"Potential error in the blinds of hand {hand_number} or in the seat assignment.")
        
        # Make the money dictionary from the InChips file data.
        try:
            money_dict = dict()
            for sitter in seat_assignment:
                money_dict[sitter] = "ERROR"
                try:
                    money = str(self.chips[sitter].where(self.chips["hand"]==int(hand_number)).values[0])
                    money = "$"+money.replace("k",",000")
                    money_dict[sitter] = money
                except:
                    self.log.append(f"Couldn't find {sitter} for hand #{hand_number} in the InChips.csv data.")
        except:
            self.log.append(f"Warning: error in determining the chips for all the players.")
        
        # Make a diction with cards from the DealthTo data.
        try:
            deal_info = dict()
            for sitter in seat_assignment:
                deal_info[sitter] = "NO CARD DATA or an ERROR"
                try:
                    cards = self.deal[sitter].where(self.deal["hand"]==int(hand_number)).values[0]
                    cards = cards.replace("t", "T").replace("j", "J").replace("q", "Q").replace("k", "K").replace("a", "A")
                    cards = f"[{cards[:2]} {cards[2:]}]"
                    deal_info[sitter] = cards
                except:
                    self.log.append(f"Couldn't find {sitter} for hand #{hand_number} the the DealtTo.csv data.")
        except:
            self.log.append(f"Warnind: error in determining the info on the deal for all the players.")
                    
        
        # The rest of the hand is the action.
        try:         
            # money_dict = dict()
            # for sitter in seat_assignment:
            #     money_dict[sitter] = "$100,000"
            action_info = lines[3:]
            # for i, line in enumerate(action_info):
                # if line.find(".")!=-1:
                    # info = line.split(" ")[0].split(".")
                    # if len(info)==3:
                        # sitter, money, cards = line.split(" ")[0].split(".")
                        # money_dict[sitter] = f"${int(money):,}"
                        # action_info[i] = line.replace(f".{money}.{cards}","")
                        # assert len(cards)==4
                        # assert cards.isalnum()
                        # cards = f"[{cards[:2]} {cards[2:]}]".replace("t", "T").replace("j", "J").replace("q", "Q").replace("k", "K").replace("a", "A")
                        # deal_info = {sitter: cards}
                    # else:
                        # sitter, money = line.split(" ")[0].split(".")
                        # money_dict[sitter] = f"${int(money):,}"
                        # action_info[i] = line.replace(f".{money}","")
        except:
            self.log.append(f"Error parsing the action section of hand {hand_number}.")
        
        datetime = datetime.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
        
        try:
            head = self.make_head(hand_number, blinds, datetime, button_seat)
        except:
            self.log.append(f"Unable to generate the first two lines of the output for hand {hand_number}.")
            head = f"Error creating first two lines for hand {hand_number}."
        try:
            seat_list = self.make_seat_list(seat_assignment, money_dict, not_at_table)
        except:
            self.log.append(f"Unable to generate the seat list with the amount of chips for hand {hand_number}.")
            seat_list = f"Error creating the seating list with the chip amounts for hand {hand_number}."
        try:
            ante = self.make_ante(seat_assignment, ante_dict, not_at_table)
        except:
            self.log.append(f"Unable to generate the seat list with the amount of chips for hand {hand_number}.")
            ante = f"Error creating the seating list with the chip amounts for hand {hand_number}."
        try:
            blind = self.make_blind(blind_sitters, blinds)
        except:
            self.log.append(f"Unable to generate the blind output for hand {hand_number}.")
            blind = f"Error creating blind output for hand {hand_number}."
        try:
            deal = self.make_deal(seat_assignment, deal_info, not_at_table)
        except:
            self.log.append(f"Unable to generate the deal output for hand {hand_number}.")
            deal = f"Error creating the deal output for hand {hand_number}."
        try:
            action = self.make_action(action_info)
        except:
            self.log.append(f"Unable to generate action for hand {hand_number}.")
            action = f"Error creating the action output for hand {hand_number}."
        
        hand = "\n".join([head, seat_list, ante, blind, deal, action])
        return hand, "\n".join(self.log)
        
    def make_head(self, hand_number, blinds, datetime, button_seat):
        return "\n".join([f"Poker Hand #HD{hand_number}: Hold'em No Limit (${'/$'.join(blinds[:2])}) - {datetime}",
                          f"Table 'VH Straddle4' 8-max Seat #{button_seat} is the button"])
    
    def make_seat_list(self, seat_assignment, money_dict, not_at_table):
        seat_list = []
        for i, sitter in enumerate(seat_assignment):
            if sitter not in not_at_table:
                seat_list.append(f"Seat {i+1}: {sitter} ({money_dict[sitter]} in chips)")
        return "\n".join(seat_list)
        
    def make_ante(self, seat_assignment, ante_dict, not_at_table):
        ante = []
        for sitter in seat_assignment:
            if sitter not in not_at_table:
                ante.append(f"{sitter}: posts the ante {ante_dict[sitter]}")
        return "\n".join(ante)
    
    def make_blind(self, blind_sitters, blinds):
        blind_type = len(blind_sitters)
        if len(blinds)<blind_type:
            blinds = blinds+["9999999999"]*(blind_type-len(blinds))
        blind = []
        if blind_type>0:
            blind.append(f"{blind_sitters[0]}: posts small blind ${int(blinds[0]):,}")
            blind.append(f"{blind_sitters[1]}: posts big blind ${int(blinds[1]):,}")
        if blind_type>2:
            blind.append(f"{blind_sitters[2]}: posts third blind ${int(blinds[2]):,}")
        if blind_type>3:
            blind.append(f"{blind_sitters[3]}: posts fourth blind ${int(blinds[3]):,}")
        if blind_type>4:
            words = ['fifth', 'sixth', 'seventh', 'eighth']
            i = 5
            for sitter, blind_ in zip(blind_sitters[4:], blinds[4:]):
                blind.append(f"{sitter}: posts {words[i-5]} blind ${int(blind_):,}")
                i += 1
        return "\n".join(blind)

    def make_deal(self, seat_assignment, deal_info, not_at_table):
        deal = ["*** HOLE CARDS ***"]
        for sitter in seat_assignment:
            if sitter not in not_at_table:
                if sitter in deal_info.keys():
                    deal.append(f"Dealt to {sitter} {deal_info[sitter]}")
                else:
                    deal.append(f"Dealt to {sitter}")
        return "\n".join(deal)
    
    def make_action(self, action_info):
        action_list = []
        for line in action_info:
            line = line.split(' ')
            if line[0]=="flop":
                cards = line[1]
                cards = f"[{cards[:2]} {cards[2:4]} {cards[4:]}]"
                cards = cards.replace("t", "T").replace("j", "J").replace("q", "Q").replace("k", "K").replace("a", "A")
                action_list.append(f"*** FLOP *** {cards}")
                continue
            if line[0]=="turn":
                cards = " ".join([cards, f"[{line[1]}]".replace("t", "T").replace("j", "J").replace("q", "Q").replace("k", "K").replace("a", "A")])
                action_list.append(f"*** TURN *** {cards}")
                continue
            if line[0]=="river":
                cards = " ".join([cards[:9], cards[12:], f"[{line[1]}]".replace("t", "T").replace("j", "J").replace("q", "Q").replace("k", "K").replace("a", "A")])
                action_list.append(f"*** RIVER *** {cards}")
                continue
            if line[1]=="wins":
                action_list.append("*** SHOWDOWN ***")
                action_list.append(f"{line[0]} collected ${int(line[2]):,} from pot")
            if line[1]=="shows":
                showncards = line[2]
                showncards = f"[{' '.join([f'{i}{j}' for i, j in zip(showncards[::2], showncards[1::2])])}]"
                showncards = showncards.replace("t", "T").replace("j", "J").replace("q", "Q").replace("k", "K").replace("a", "A")
                action_list.append(f"{line[0]}: shows {showncards}")
            action = line[1]
            if action=="c":
                action_list.append(f"{line[0]}: calls ${int(line[2]):,}")
            if action=="f":
                action_list.append(f"{line[0]}: folds")
            if action=="r":
                action_list.append(f"{line[0]}: raises ${int(line[2]):,} to ${int(line[4]):,}")
            if action=="b":
                action_list.append(f"{line[0]}: bets ${int(line[2]):,}")
            if action=="x":
                action_list.append(f"{line[0]}: checks")
        return "\n".join(action_list)

if __name__=="__main__":
    # import sys
    # inputfilename = sys.argv[1]
    # print(f"opening file {inputfilename}")

    
    # inputfilename = input("Enter the name of the main input file: ")
    chipfilename = "InChips.csv"
    dealfilename = "DealtTo.csv"
    deal = pd.read_csv(dealfilename, skipinitialspace=True)
    chip = pd.read_csv(chipfilename, skipinitialspace=True)
    inputfilename = "Input.txt"
    with open(inputfilename, 'r') as  f:
        game_input = "".join(f.readlines())
        PokerGame(game_input, deal, chip).output_hands("Output.txt")
```

sin embargo el output que arroja es :

```
Poker Hand #HD1: Hold'em No Limit ($500/$500) - 2023/03/08 10:07:02
Table 'VH Straddle4' 8-max Seat #3 is the button
Seat 1: gg (ERROR in chips)
Seat 2: yy (ERROR in chips)
Seat 3: dj (ERROR in chips)
Seat 4: rj (ERROR in chips)
Seat 5: aw (ERROR in chips)
Seat 6: zz (ERROR in chips)
gg: posts the ante $0
yy: posts the ante $0
dj: posts the ante $0
rj: posts the ante $0
aw: posts the ante $500
zz: posts the ante $0
rj: posts small blind $500
aw: posts big blind $500
*** HOLE CARDS ***
Dealt to gg NO CARD DATA or an ERROR
Dealt to yy NO CARD DATA or an ERROR
Dealt to dj NO CARD DATA or an ERROR
Dealt to rj NO CARD DATA or an ERROR
Dealt to aw NO CARD DATA or an ERROR
Dealt to zz NO CARD DATA or an ERROR
zz: calls $500
gg: raises $1,000 to $1,500
yy: folds
dj: folds
rj: folds
aw: folds
zz: calls $1,000
```

ya me estoy quedando sin ideas, no se que mas intentar

esto es el Correct output. lo que querría que diga:

```
Poker Hand #HD1: Hold'em No Limit ($500/$500) - 2023/03/08 10:07:02
Table 'VH Straddle4' 8-max Seat #3 is the button
Seat 1: gg ($500,000 in chips)
Seat 2: yy ($500,000 in chips)
Seat 3: dj ($500,000 in chips)
Seat 4: rj ($499,000 in chips)
Seat 5: aw ($499,000 in chips)
Seat 6: zz ($500,000 in chips)
gg: posts the ante $0
yy: posts the ante $0
dj: posts the ante $0
rj: posts the ante $0
aw: posts the ante $500
zz: posts the ante $0
rj: posts small blind $500
aw: posts big blind $500
*** HOLE CARDS ***
Dealt to gg [2s Kd]
Dealt to yy [Ts 3s]
Dealt to dj [Js 2s]
Dealt to rj [4c 5s]
Dealt to aw [Ac 5h]
Dealt to zz [2h 3h]
zz: calls $500
gg: raises $1,000 to $1,500
yy: folds
dj: folds
rj: folds
aw: folds
```

Comment: Pareciera que no tienes info en `money_dict` cuando imprimes los asientos.

Comment: Hola Ariel, sigo esperando como chiquilla de quince años, los ejemplos de entradas, sin ellos es imposible saber que falla.